# Remove unwanted id for a control when declared in asp:content in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Consider sample piece of code in asp.net which has a master page associated with it

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderA" Runat="Server" >
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxB" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" Height="96px" Width="426px" />
</asp:Content>
```

When the page is rendered in browser id generated for textbox with id "TextBoxB" is

```
ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderA_TextBoxB
```

Below is the equivalent html code.

```
 <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderA$TextBoxB" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderA_TextBoxB" style="height:96px;width:426px;" />
```

Is it possible to have same id of TextBoxB in both HTML and aspx page.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you using .Net 4, or a previous version?

Answer (score 0):

No. The ID has to be unique on the HTML page, but there's no way for the ASPX page to be certain that the ID you've given is unique - it could be duplicated in for example the master page, in a user control, etc, and then you end up with two identical IDs in the output.

To get around this, ASP.NET guarantees unique IDs by qualifying an ID with the IDs of containing controls.

Comment: Thanks for the solution chris.

Just a wild thought.
If a master page, user controls or etc has a control with same id the compiler should generate the error of same as we are specifying the master page to be used at design time.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using .NET 4.0 (I guess @Nick means the same) you could set `ClientIDMode="Static"` so control would have the same ID as it has in markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you not using .net 4.0, but you wont  to have the same id (on the html page and server side)

try this:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public override string UniqueID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ID;
        }
    }
}


    MyTextBox textBox= new MyTextBox();
    textBox.ID = "id";
    textBox.Text = "text";       
    this.Page.Controls.add(textBox);
```